# Angular 1.6+ - How to set ng-options dynamically from the DB using the element inside a forEach loop

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-directive, foreach, angularjs-ng-options

I want to take a response from a web service and apply it to the ng-options inside the angular.forEach loop. All I think I have to access it is the element itself. Here is the code. Normally I would just write:

```
scope.whatIWantTheOptionsToB = DBResponse;
```

But inside the forEach loop I can't do that. How would I set the options variable inside the for each loop.

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="form__row">
            <label>Injury Type:</label>
            <select
                class="form__select"
                ws="populateDDL"
                param="tblInjuryTypes"
                ng-model="injuryType_id"
                ng-options="injury.id as injury.name for injury in injuryTypes"
                ng-change="injuryUpdate()"
                name="injuryTypes"
                required
            ></select>
        </div>

    <div class="form__row">
        <label>Work Status:</label>
        <select
            class="form__select"
            ws="populateDDL"
            param="tblWorkStatus"
            ng-model="workStatus_id"
            ng-options="status.id as status.name for status in workStatus"
            name="workStatus"
            required
        ></select>
    </div>
```

Directive:

```
   app.directive(
        'providerForm',
        ['$http', 'populateDDL', 'classHandler', function ($http, populateDDL, classHandler){
            var directive = {
                link: link,
                scope: true,
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/modules/providerForm.html',
            };
            return directive;
            function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var selects = element.find('select');
                angular.forEach(selects, function(e,i) {
                    if (e.attributes['ws'].value === 'populateDDL') {
                        scope.data = {
                            sKey: sessionStorage.getItem('key'),
                            sTableName: e.attributes['param'].value,
                            iInjuryTypeId: scope.injuryType_id,
                            iBodyPartId: scope.bodyPart_id
                        };
                        scope.getSelectOptions = new populateDDL(e.attributes['ws'].value, scope.data).
                        then(function(response) {
                            console.log(e)
                            scope.whatIWantTheOptionsToBeEachTimeThru = response;
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        }]
    );
```

Comment: Why would you do this from js versus using a ng-options or ng-repeat in your markup?

Comment: I am using ng-options but I get the data from the database to fill the option list

Comment: Right, so if you did something like this in your markup, ng-options="item as item.label for item in whatIWantTheOptionsToBeEachTimeThru" your options would be updated every time scope.whatIWantTheOptionsToBeEachTimeThru changes

Comment: I have to assign the reponse to scope.whatIWantTheOptionsToBeEachTimeThru but scope.whatIWantTheOptionsToBeEachTimeThru changes everytime through the forEach loop

Comment: see edits I just made please...

Comment: Ok, I was just going to say its kinda hard to help stear you in the right direction without more code.  A plunk would be better still.  On the surface this looks like overkill ...

Comment: First time through the loop I would need to attach the response to: injuryTypes and the second I would need to attach to: workStatus

Comment: There are 20-30 selects that all have logic in different ng-change functions I assure you its not overkill

Comment: Based on your second comment can you propose how that is done?

Comment: A working plunk would help.  I don't want to send you off in the wrong direction just because I don't have enough context to fully understand the issue.  That's where a plunk would be helpful.

Comment: Im calling web services on my server... The data gets passed back in different types of objects.... We can work together Im not a noob.